# Inheritance variables in c#

Tags: c#, inheritance

Just for practice I'm trying to write a calculator program. To make it difficult I trying to use some of the advanced inheritance topics I've learned, but not really used. Lets say you have an interface named `IMath` with one method `string DoMath()`. Is it possible to have a variable written in the `IMath` interface that all classes implementing that interface would see new values? So for example my class `Add : IMath` would have the method `DoMath()` and in that `DoMath()` method would change the value of the variable `double ITotal` which all classes that implement the IMath interface would see the new value.

Comment: Why `string DoMath`, and not `double DoMath`?

Comment: because the output on the calculator is a string. I send a string, I should get a string back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like what you're looking for is an [abstract](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/sf985hc5%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) base class.

One possible implementation of what you describe is shown below.

```
public abstract class MathBase
{
    public double Total { get; protected set; }

    public abstract string DoMath(double value);

    protected double ParseValue(string value)
    {
        double parsedValue;

        if (!double.TryParse(value, out parsedValue))
        {
            throw new ArgumentException(string.Format("The value '{0}' is not a number.", value), "value");
        }

        return parsedValue;
    }
}

public class Add : MathBase
{
    public override string DoMath(string value)
    {
        Total += ParseValue(value);

        return Convert.ToString(Total);
    }
}
```

If you wanted every instance of every class that inherits from `MathBase` to share the same `Total` value, you would declare it as `static`:

```
public abstract class MathBase
{
    public static double Total { get; protected set; }

    public abstract string DoMath(string value);
}
```

(although I'm not really sure why you would want this)

Comment: when you update protected double _total, will all classes implementing MathBase see the update?

Comment: I do want them to share the same value, for instance I call Subtract : MathBase, Subtract can use the number to be subtracted and the current total, then multiply, divide can all do that too

Comment: I'm trying it out now, but it seems like this is what I'm looking for. I have a job interview tomorrow and wanted to show/(refresh my memory) that I can use some of these advanced methods.

Answer (score 5):

You cannot specify variables or fields in interfaces, you can only specify:

- Methods
- Properties
- Indexers
- Events

See [the C# documentation on interfaces](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/87d83y5b%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) for more information about this.

An interface dictates expected behavior, it does not dictate expected implementation. A property can be read as "the ability to retrieve the value of X" or "the ability to provide the value of X", where as a variable is "the ability to store X". This is not the same thing, and interfaces cannot make that guarantee.

If you absolutely need to enforce the presence of a variable, you should use a base class. I would probably look into combining these things, use interfaces for the external interface (ie. how should my calculator function) and base class and inheritance to avoid rewriting the same code over and over.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
interface IMath
{
    string DoMath();
}

abstract class MathBase : IMath
{
    protected double Total { get; set; }

    public abstract string DoMath();
}

class Add : MathBase
{
    public override string DoMath()
    {
        this.Total = 2;

        return "2";
    }
}
```

Comment: would all classes implementing MathBase see the new value?

Comment: Yes they would, as the Total property is protected, which means that only the base class itself or any classes inheriting from it can access it.